# How can I place an activity indictor in a button at a certain distance from the text in the button?

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a button which when clicked an activity indictor appears within the button, the indicator should be just infront of the button's text.
I'd tried adding this constraint but its not having any effect. Is this constraint incorrect, what should it be?

```
  _ = continueButton.titleLabel?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityIndicator.trailingAnchor)
```

There is an existing constraint in the storyboard to center horizontally the activity indicator in the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then your anchors should look something like this:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
        self.activityIndicator.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.titleLabel.leadingAnchor, constant: -5)
        self.activityIndicator.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.titleLabel.topAnchor)
        ])
```